# why character are called Integral type in C programming language?

Tags: c, integer, character

I am currently studying C language. I was studying Datatypes, please tell me, why characters are called integral constants?

Comment: @CherryDT ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, with values from `0` to `127` (inclusive). Also note that it's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned (i.e. its range could be `-128` to `127`).

Comment: Thank you sir  for clearing my doubt.

Comment: Btw formally nothing is called an _integral_ type in C any longer. That term was switched to _integer_ type 22 years ago.

Comment: @CherryDT, That's not true, not even on common modern machinery. It's common for `char` to be a number between -128..127.

Comment: @Beginner, Because they are. `'a'` is exactly equivalent to `65` (on ASCII-based compiler).

Comment: @CherryDT The range of char isn't always 0..255 like you said. It's often -128..127. If it was 0..255 as it is on some systems, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69797756/589924) code would have run without problem. I don't know how else to say this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may perform integer operations with objects of the type `char`. For example you may decrease or increase a value stored in an object of the type char, or add or subtract a value.

For example if an object of the type char contains a symbol that represents a digit as for example

```
char c = '5';
```

then you can get the digit as a number the following way

```
int digit = c - '0';
```

The variable digit will contain the number `5`.

Pay attention to that the type `char` can behave either as the type `signed char` or `unsigned char` dependent on compiler options.

In C opposite to C++ integer character constants have the type `int` .

Answer (score 1):

Because they are represented with non-modifiable integer values.

For ASCII characters, for example, these values range between 0 and 255.

Comment: For _ASCII_ characters, they range from 0 to 127.

Comment: ASCII is a 7-bit encoding, with values from `0` to `127` (inclusive). Also note that it's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned (i.e. its range could be `-128` to `127`).